# How to get the POST data from a form inside of an iframe

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

I have a form inside of an iframe in my CodeIgniter application:

```
<div class="settings"><h2>Einstellungen</h2>
  <div class="main-content">
    <iframe src="" name="main-content">
      <form id="new-role-form" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('index.php/home/settings') ?>">
        <input class="role-input" type="text" placeholder="Rolle" name="role"><input class="role-input" type="password" placeholder="Passwort" name="password"><button class="button role-submit" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
      </form>
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

When submitting this form the following code should be executed (the submit is working I tested it; I can get the inputs of the form here):

```
$(document).on('submit', '#new-role-form', function(event) {
            var form = $(this);
            var name = $('input[name="role"]', form).val();
            var password = $('input[name="password"]', form).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo base_url('index.php/ajax/insertRole'); ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {name: name, password: password},
                success: function() {
                    alert("success");
                }
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
```

And this is the insertRole function of my ajax controller:

```
public function insertRole() {
        $this->Database->insert($this->input->post('name'), $this->input->post('password'));
    }
```

This is where I get the error: `...index.php/ajax/insertRole 500 (Internal Server Error)`

How can I retrieve the POST data from a form inside an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems catching the 'submit' event you could use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#frame').load(function() {
        $(this).contents().find('form').submit(function() {
            //do your stuff here
        });
    });
</script>
```

In order to 'wait' for the iframe being loaded and then catch the submit event. You also could create a function in the main file:

```
function valueFromIframe(val) {
   alert(val)
}
```

And call from the iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 parent.valueFromIframe("Hello world");
</script>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This doesn't even answer my question. My submit event is firing perfectly fine.

Comment: The name of the question: "How to get the POST data from a form inside of an iframe" and your final question: "How can I retrieve the POST data from a form inside an iframe?" makes me think that you aren't able to get the $_POST from your iframe... If you have a 500 Server error try to echo the $_POST inside the `insertRole()` (in order to prove that the info is really there)  and check that `$this->Database` is defined. Usually I try to variate betweeno single and double quotes to avoid problems (I mean in: `"<?php echo base_url('index.php/ajax/insertRole'); ?>"` )

Comment: After some testing it seems like my only error was an invalid SQL query but thanks for the help :)